# regex to mask phone number such that except first 2 and last 2 characters in a number are replaced with * in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Convert the given number 557878767 to 55*****67

Comment: what have you tried already?  read [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question. regards

Comment: Currently used this in react native, 
phoneRegEx = /(?!^.?).(?!.{0}$)/
 but it gives exception

Comment: click on [edit] to improve it, not in comments. read the [tour] also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does precisely what you asked for however without using regex:

```
function convert(number){
    number = String(number)
    length = number.length-4
    middle = '*'.repeat(length)
    return number[0]+number[1]+middle+number[number.length-2]+number[number.length-1]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can substitute `(?<=\d\d)\d(?=\d\d)` with `*`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IcSN7M/1

**UPDATE:** For better cross-browser compatibility, lookbehind patterns should be avoided. As a workaround, you can effectively "skip" the first two digits by capturing the first two digits and "replace" them with themselves using a backreference.

Try it out:

```js
var str = "557878767";
str = str.replace(/\b(\d\d)\d|\d(?=\d\d)/g, "$1*");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stackoverflow

You can mask the phone number in single line (using regex).

```js
var str = "557878767";
str = str.replace(/(?<=\d\d)\d(?=\d{2})/g, "*");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: This uses lookbehind and thus requires ES2018 disqualifying IE and Edge.